# Bug of compiler or boost library?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-asio

This program (it has been narrowed down from a larger program) always crashes after compiled in vs2008 Release(Win32) mode under windows 7. I am not familiar with assembly code and don't know it's a bug of compiler or boost::ends_with or boost::asio::buffers_iterator. It can be compiled and executed with g++ in Ubuntu without any problem.

People said it's very unlikely to be compiler's bug, but when compiled in debug moded(or disable optimization), the problem does disappear.

I have been stuck with this problem for quite a few hours. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

typedef boost::asio::buffers_iterator<boost::asio::const_buffers_1> iterator_t;
typedef boost::iterator_range<iterator_t> range_t;
static const std::string LINE_END_MARK = "\r\n";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::streambuf _buf;
    std::ostream os(&_buf);
    os<<"END\r\n";

    iterator_t cursor = boost::asio::buffers_begin(_buf.data());
    iterator_t end = boost::asio::buffers_end(_buf.data());

    std::ostream_iterator<char> it(std::cout," ");
    std::copy(LINE_END_MARK.begin(), LINE_END_MARK.end(), it);

    range_t r(cursor, end);
    if(!boost::ends_with(r, LINE_END_MARK))
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I can repro your crash with VS2008 but not with VS2010.

Comment: did you compile Boost ASIO? I think thats one of the few things that needs to be compiled

Comment: asio is a header-only library, but it relies on boost::system, which needs a separate compilation.

Comment: Have you done all the 'stupid stuff' like delete all compiled items and re-build? Are you certain that your build of boost used all the same compiler options as your app build?

Comment: in VS2005, with boost 1.50, this main returns 0 in release, and 1 in debug

Comment: Tried this on Linux 3.2.0 with GCC 4.6.3, and there was no crash and no errors under valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I misread the code, sorry.

Your cursor and end iterators are pointing to invalid memory. You modified the underlying streambuf which reallocated during the copy to the output iterator. asio streambuf lets you access the raw memory for performance reasons, but the caveat is you have to worry about things like this.

Debug and release will change the way allocation and deallocation behave with regards to the underlying size of the allocated block and how memory may be fenced, guarded, initialized, aligned, etc.

Construct your iterators after the copy operation to fix your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - the `std::copy()` operation to the output iterator occurs to `std::cout`.  The `asio::streambuf` is associated with `os` not `cout`.  Writing to `cout` shouldn't affect `os`.

Comment: You are right of course; I misread this. I am perplexed and will have to give this some further consideration. Would not be the first bug in asio streambuf at least.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because 'range_t r(cursor, end)' is a range of "buffers" not a range of characters.  So you are comparing a list of buffer pointers with each character in LINE_END_MARK.

If crashes in release mode under win32 because in windows you end up de-referencing a null pointer causing the crash.

boost asio has this concept of multiple buffers, but currently it's not really used.  If you look at the implementation if only really uses 'const_buffers_1' or 'mutable_buffers_1' which is basically a list of 1 buffer.

I assume you want to compare the contents of the buffer, not a list of buffers range.

So you want to do something like:

```
typedef boost::iterator_range<const char*> range_t;
range_t r(boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(_buf.data()), boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(_buf.data()) + boost::asio::buffer_size(_buf.data()));
if(!boost::ends_with(r, LINE_END_MARK))
    return 0;
return 1;
```

Comment: Came to the same conclusion as well. The multiple buffers support can be a bit confusing at times.

Comment: @Shane Powell I don't agree. From the document of asio, buffers_begin returns the iterator to the data instead of buffer sequence. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html   The buffers_iterator<> class template allows buffer sequences (i.e. types meeting MutableBufferSequence or ConstBufferSequence requirements) to be traversed as though they were a contiguous sequence of bytes.